# POST data to web service HttpWebRequest Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've been trying without success today to adapt this example to POST data instead of the example GET that is provided.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/02/07/async-and-await-for-http-networking-on-windows-phone.aspx

I've replaced the line:

```
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
```

With

```
 request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
```

But can find no Method that will allow me to stream in the content I wish to POST.

This HttpWebRequest seems a lot cleaner than other ways e.g. sending delegate functions to handle the response.

In Mr Wigley's example code I can see POST so it must be possible

```
 public static class HttpMethod
    {
        public static string Head { get { return "HEAD"; } }
        public static string Post { get { return "POST"; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this class some time ago

```
  public class JsonSend<I, O>
    {
        bool _parseOutput;
        bool _throwExceptionOnFailure;

        public JsonSend()
            : this(true,true)
        {

        }

        public JsonSend(bool parseOutput, bool throwExceptionOnFailure)
        {
            _parseOutput = parseOutput;
            _throwExceptionOnFailure = throwExceptionOnFailure;
        }

        public async Task<O> DoPostRequest(string url, I input)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(
                url,
                "action",
                "post",
                DateTime.Now.Ticks
                ));

            string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);

            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(
                serialized,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");

            var response = client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);

            HttpResponseMessage x = await response;
            HttpContent requestContent = x.Content;
            string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (x.IsSuccessStatusCode == false && _throwExceptionOnFailure)
            {
                throw new Exception(url + " with POST ends with status code " + x.StatusCode + " and content " + jsonContent);
            }

            if (_parseOutput == false){
                return default(O);
            }

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<O>(jsonContent);
        }

        public async Task<O> DoPutRequest(string url, I input)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages[0]);                    

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(
                url,
                "action",
                "put",
                DateTime.Now.Ticks
                ));

            string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
            var response = client.PutAsync(uri,
            new StringContent(
                serializedObject,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage x = await response;
            HttpContent requestContent = x.Content;
            string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            if (x.IsSuccessStatusCode == false && _throwExceptionOnFailure)
            {
                throw new Exception(url + " with PUT ends with status code " + x.StatusCode + " and content " + jsonContent);
            }

            if (_parseOutput == false){
                return default(O);
            }

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<O>(jsonContent);
        }
    }
```

Then when I want to call it, I can use it as following :

```
JsonSend<User, RegistrationReceived> register = new JsonSend<User, RegistrationReceived>();
RegistrationReceived responseUser = await register.DoPostRequest("http://myurl", user);
```